# The Delete link on my records table is not working php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table that displays titled and first name columns and delete link on the 3rd column.

Unfortunately for a reason i don't understand, records are not deleting when the Delete link is clicked.

Please friends, help me figure out what's wrong here.

```
<?php 

  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"]; //brought here via 
                                    session
   //select statement here
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<tr>
              <td scope="row">' . $row["titled"]. '</td>
              <td> '.$row["firstname"] .'</td>
              <td><a href="user_delete.php? 
                  delete=$row[user_id]">Delete</a>
              </td>


          </tr>';
   }


   } else {
   echo "0 results";
   }


   ?>
```

user_delete.php code

```
   <?php
   session_start();
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
   `enter code here`'/soap/includes/server.php';


    if(isset($_GET["delete"]) )
   {
    $user_id = $_GET["delete"];
    $sql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    $res= mysqli_query($con, $sql) or 
    die("Failed".mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' 
    content='0;url=user_settings.php'>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: When you click that link, where does it take you? Does the URL look correct to you? `user_delete.php?delete=$row[user_id]"` should be `user_delete.php?delete=' . $row[user_id] . '"`

Comment: Note: `$row[user_id]` should have quotes: `$row['user_id']`. Also, I hope you secure this a little, because users WILL play around with adding different user ids to the url and removing users from your system

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I will also give more to security. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

While you must debug code and add results for check what could be the issue. But one issue I think is using variable $row[user_id] in single quoted string. PHP do not parse variable in single quoted string. So either transfer all html code from single to double quotes or atleast append $row[user_id] seperatly like other $row[firstname]

```
echo '<tr>
          <td scope="row">' . $row["titled"]. '</td>
          <td> '.$row["firstname"] .'</td>
          <td><a href="user_delete.php? 
              delete='.$row["user_id"].'">Delete</a>
          </td>


      </tr>'
```